# Getting word count from webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Cleans text (removes any punctuation)
def CleanText(text):
    text = str(text)
    forbidden = [r'\n', r'.', r'?', r'!', r'(', r')']
    for i in forbidden:
        text.replace(i, '')
    return text

# returns count of a word from a page
def ReturnCount(url, word):
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    words = str(soup.find(text=lambda text: text and word in text))
    words = CleanText(words.lower())
    words = words.split()
    return words.count(word.lower())
```

I'm trying to get the frequency (occurrence) of a particular word on a webpage. However, I'm always getting 0 as the output.

the count as 0, despite having multiple occurrences of that word
Output: `0`

Comment: Could you provide also `url` and `word` to reproduce, please.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not realy sure why you need

```
words = str(soup.find(text=lambda text: text and word in text))
```

make it simple

```
def ReturnCount(url, word):
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    words = CleanText(soup.text.lower())
    words = words.split()
    return words.count(word.lower())

wordCount = ReturnCount('http://example.com/', 'in')
print(wordCount) # 3
```

Answer (score 0):

**There are different things going on:**

- You try to get all `text` with `find()`, that only get the first occurrence
- Instead try to use `find_all()` that gets all occurrences
- Not sure what your `lambda` is doing there
- `soup.body.find_all(text=True)` get all the `text` from inside the `body` tag, process the list and join by `''.join([t for t in soup.body.find_all(text=True)])` to a `string`

**Example:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Cleans text (removes any punctuation)
def CleanText(text):
    text = str(text)
    forbidden = [r'\n', r'.', r'?', r'!', r'(', r')']
    for i in forbidden:
        text.replace(i, '')
    return text

# returns count of a word from a page
def ReturnCount(url, word):
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    words = ''.join([t for t in soup.body.find_all(text=True)])
    words = CleanText(words.lower())
    words = words.split()
    return words.count(word.lower())

ReturnCount('https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/microsoft-365/word','word')
```

**Output:**
`13`

Comment: It doesn't give any result. It just passes, without returning any value

Comment: Did you changed this line `words = str(soup.find(text=lambda text: text and word in text))` -->  `words = ''.join([t for t in soup.body.find_all(text=True)])`